# LCD screen panel stuck in BIST mode

Tags: lcd, testing, glcd

I have a BOE DV430FHM-NN0 LCD screen panel with an LVDS 30-pin receptacle cable. It was happily working with a M.NT68676 board, but one day when I connected it to the same board, the panel suddenly went into a weird status, repeating only white, black, red, green and blue screens even if the cable was disconnected.

After some inspections, I found it was called BIST (built-in self test) mode. I found a datasheet for it via Google, but it only mentioned the existence of the BIST mode, not how to enter or exit from it.

How can I make this panel exit from the BIST mode and accept LVDS signal as it did before?

Comment: At a guess, look for a short (even a bit of conductive rubber from the connector) between two pins. You might check with an ohmeter, and the resistance could be higher than a dead short.